# How do you access shared folders on a Windows machine from a MacBook Air?

Tags: windows, file-transfer

How do I connect to my Windows machine from my MacBook Air? I have tried using the Finder but it doesn't see the Windows machine.

Comment: 1) Are both machines on the same network?
2) Is File & Print Sharing enabled on the Windows machine's active network connection?
3) Have any shares been created on the Windows machine?
4) If #3 is a yes, what permissions have been set for those shares?
5) Presuming you've dealt with #'s 3 & 4, are you attempting to access said shares via a user account which has the proper access and permissions for the shares?  Typically, 1-3 absolutely need to happen before the Windows machine will even show up in the Finder sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Command-K in the Finder

The address should be `smb://<Windows IP or Hostname>`

Hope this helps!

Comment: it might be good to add something there: smb://[Windows IP Address]/c$. If you add the "/c$" at the end it will explicitly map to the root of the boot drive which is usually "C" then give it a username in the form of "[computername]\administrator" and the the Administrator's password. You can substitute your own username in place of administrator if you have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both machines are on the same network.
2. File sharing is enabled on the windows machine's active network connection. Also both machines are using the same workgroup.
3. Yes, shares have been created on the windows machine.The shares are read write enabled.
4. Changed the shares to be public guest accessible and visible on all networks and then they finally showed up in the finder.

Comment: Please edit your original post to add the request information, rather than posting as an answer.